# Can't resize extended partition

Tags: partition, gparted

I want to add 7GB (unallocated) to the extended partition SDA3, but when I go to "resize/move" I can't add any more space; those 7GB are only available to add to the NTFS parition (SDA2), which is from where I steal them. See the picture, I'm using GPARTED on liveCD:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Move /dev/sda2 to the beginning of the unallocated space.  optionally shrink /dev/sda2 at the same time.
- then move /dev/sda3 to immediately after /dev/sda2
- extend /dev/sda3 to take up the unallocated space
- then move /dev/sda6 to the end of the extended partition (/dev/sda3)
- and finally extend /dev/sda5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i dont understand what "move sda2 to the beginning of the unallocated space" means, is going to sda2-> resize/move and move the bar all to the left? Same with "move /dev/sda3 to immediately after /dev/sda2"

Comment: the unallocated space is before /dev/sda2.  what i said means move /dev/sda2 so that the unallocated space is after it.  optionally shrink sda2 at the same time.

Comment: the point of all this partition shuffling is so that you end up with the unallocated space immediately after /dev/sda5, so sda5 can be extended.

Comment: How do you "move" a partition? Mine don't move

Comment: @JoePhillips do you have any empty, unallocated space on the disk that a partition could be moved to?   can you shrink a partition to make some unallocated space?  BTW, if you have a specific problem you're having trouble with then post a new question, don't ask in comments to an old & unrelated question.

Comment: Figured it out. I had to 'deactivate' the partitions first, otherwise everything else in this answer was related. I'd even go as far to say that this answer is missing that step